# How to store distances between places?

Tags: php, mysql, storage

I have a database containing places, and I need to show distances from any place to other ones in my webpage. Having the distances stored somewhere will save lots of work (loading them should be easier than computing them anew). But how to save the square matrix of the distances? Creating a new column every time I insert a new row doesn't seem to be a good solution, but I didn't find any better *solution* (though I can think of workarounds such as computing some 10 or 20 nearest distances and assuming I will rarely need more).

What is optimal way to save square tables of variable (and growing) size in PHP/MySQL? Or is there no good solution and my (or some other) workaround is better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Edit Note: As was mentioned in a comment, once you get enough places it may make more sense to just store long/lat values and calculate the distance on the fly based on those instead. However the solution explained here may still be relevant for other applications.*

---

The best way to handle this would be with a pivot table, where each row has two place id's, and a distance value.

Now, since Distance A-B is the same as B-A, we only need to store each pairing once. We can do this by only ever storing a distance if the ID of A is less than B.

---

## SETUP

First a `places` table to store your places

```
id | name
---+---------
 1 | Place_A
 2 | Place_B
 3 | Place_C
 4 | Place_D
```

Then a `places_distances` Pivot table:

```
place_id_1 | place_id_2 | distance
-----------+------------+----------
         1 |          2 | 10.0
         1 |          3 | 20.0
         1 |          4 | 15.0
         2 |          3 | 12.0
         2 |          4 |  8.0
         3 |          4 | 14.0
```

Note that pivot tables do not need their own ID field (though some may argue it's still good to have one sometimes). You will set up a unique key as follows (you'll want to look into the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) for correct usage):

```
UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_placesDistances_primary`(`place_id_1`,`place_id_2`)
```

This ensures that you cannot have the same place/place paring in the table twice.

You will also want to make sure to set up foreign keys:

```
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY `FK_placesDistances_place1` (`place_id_1`) 
    REFERENCES `places`(`id`),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY `FK_placesDistances_place2` (`place_id_2`)
    REFERENCES `places`(`id`)
```

Which will ensure that you can only add entries for place you actually have defined in `places`. it also means (if you use the default foreign key behavior) that you can't delete a place if you have distance row referencing that place.

---

## Usage Examples

**Looking up the distance between two places**

(Given two variables `@id_1` as the id of the first place and `@id_2` as the id of the second place)

```
SELECT `distance`
FROM `places_distances`
WHERE (`place_id_1` = @id_1 AND `place_id_2` = @id_2)
    OR (`place_id_2` = @id_1 AND `place_id_11` = @id_2)
LIMIT 1;
```

We use the OR to account for the case where we try to look up distance `2` to `1` and not `1` to `2` - remember, we only store values where the first place's id is less than the second to avoid storing duplicates.

---

**Inserting a new distance**

(Given three variables `@id_1` as the id of the first place and `@id_2` as the id of the second place, and `@distance` being the distance)

```
INSERT `places_distances`(`place_id_1`,`place_id_2`,`distance`)
    VALUES(LEAST(@id_1, @id_2),GREATEST(@id_1, @id_2), @distance)
```

We're using the built in [comparison functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html) `LEAST` and `GREATEST` to help maintain our rule that we only store places where the first ID is less than the second, to avoid duplicates.

---

**Showing a list of place names, sorted by their distance from furthest to closest**

To get the original names from the `places` table to show up in our `places_distances` query we have to join them together. In this case `LEFT JOIN` is the best choice since we only care about what is in the `places_distances` table. [For more info on MySQL joins check here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

```
SELECT 
    `p_1`.`name` AS `place_1`,
    `p_2`.`name` AS `place_2`,
    `distance`
FROM `places_distances`
LEFT JOIN `places` AS `p_1`
    ON `distances`.`place_id_1` = `p_1`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `places` AS `p_2`
    ON `distances`.`place_id_2` = `p_2`.`id`
ORDER BY `distance` DESC
```

Which should return a table like this:

```
place_id_1 | place_id_2 | distance
-----------+------------+----------
   Place_A |    Place_C | 20.0
   Place_A |    Place_D | 15.0
   Place_C |    Place_D | 14.0
   Place_B |    Place_C | 12.0
   Place_A |    Place_B | 10.0
   Place_B |    Place_D |  8.0
```

---

**showing a table of places and their distances to a specific given place**

This is a bit more tricky since we need to show the name in a row that is not our input place, but we can use another useful function `IF(CONDITION,'TRUE_OUTPUT','FALSE_OUTPUT')` to do that.

(`@place_name` being the variable containing the place name, in this case 'Place_B')

```
SELECT 
    IF(`p_1`.`name`=@place_name, `p_2`.`name`, `p_1`.`name`) AS `name`,
    `distance`
FROM `places_distances`
LEFT JOIN `places` AS `p_1`
    ON `distances`.`place_id_1` = `p_1`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `places` AS `p_2`
    ON `distances`.`place_id_2` = `p_2`.`id`
WHERE `p_1`.`name` = @place_name OR `p_2`.`name` = @place_name
ORDER BY `distance` DESC
```

Which should return a table like this:

```
   name | distance
--------+-----------
Place_C | 12.0
Place_A | 10.0
Place_D |  8.0
```

Comment: This post is good enough, you don't need to edit it over and over until it goes community wiki :-)

Comment: Heh, sorry, I had a few errors that prevented my code from running. I should have tested it beforehand.

Comment: I didn't test it either. Now it should be an excellent answer. I will use it, thanks!

Comment: `you can't delete a place if you have distance row referencing that place.` I would change this myself that way you can easily delete places without having to worry about first deleting from the `places_distances` table.

Comment: yeah, that depends entirely on how you set up your foreign key. by default they are set to blocking, but if you set them to `cascade` then deleting the place will automatically delete any row containing a reference to that place id.

Comment: @Johannes I like your use of LEAST and GREATEST on inserts. I never thought of doing it like that before. I'm always doing that sort of logic in PHP. but your way makes it much easier +1

Answer (score 3):

I would store the lat/long for all places and write a function to calculate distance between them with the lat/long information.

In this way, no need to calculate the distances for new places you want to add in you DB.

Moreover if you have lots of places, using a pivot table to store only the distances, you have to be aware that this table can grow very fast. As you need to cover all combinaisons of places.

For instance: for 1000 places you will have 1000 * 1000 - 1000 = 999000 rows in your table. Do the math for larger number but this table might contain a lot a rows depends on how many places you've got.

Comment: Already implemented. I can't believe it would be faster than loading the data from DB, especially with haversine formula distance calculation (if you prove it is faster, you have my +1, but no chance to be accepted).

Comment: @Pavel I have a site built and in production that does it just like this. Here is the best reason why it is faster. Say you have 100 places and then add one. you need now to calculate 101 distances and insert them into the table... now what if you have 1,000 places or 10,000 places. the insert of a new place will take longer and longer compared to what the 1/2 second it takes to calculate the distance every time vs the 5 min it would take to calculate 10,000 distances of a new insert. you have to think about the long run not just the immediate.

Comment: @amaster507: unless I save places in proximity somewhere, I don't know which distances I need to compute in "near places search", which will be much more common than inserting new places and would require similar (exactly the same?) computation. Off course, I can constraint the search somehow, but I can similarly constraint the computation of distances saved to the database and save just some distances. However, I leave you that +1 because your solution would be best under different circumstances and I didn't specify why I need it.

Comment: @Pavel if you use lat/long then you can easily draw a box around what location you want to search near and then compute the distances of that subquery and return only the ones in a circle (within a given radius/distance). I found a great article and tutorial for doing just this somewhere, will post it if I can find it again. This way you are not needing to compute the exact distance for all places just the ones that are in that quadrant.

Comment: @Pavel Ah I found it searching my chrome history :) [Selecting points within a bounding circle](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html)

Comment: @amaster507: thanks. I have decided (mostly while thinking of what you and TheEwook on one hand and Johannes on the other hand wrote) to save some (50 at most, probably much less) distances to a pivot table. SQL search with Johannes' SELECT over 50.000 entries should be faster than average 2000 square and 10 to 200 (place density varies) detailed computations, and my database is unlikely to grow much bigger. Inserting is no problem, because search to insert ratio should be somewhere near 1000:1 when the site will run.

Comment: @Pavel, yeah it is all based upon the need of the application. what works in my situation may not be best in you situation. I understand that. Thanks for considering and choosing what fits your situation best but also realizing that it is not a cookie cutter fit all solution.

Comment: Performance test (with a very simple distance-computing algorithm and with just 13 places and all distances between them; all distances from one place were computed/loaded from DB) shown that computing the distances anew every time is much faster than loading them from database. I'm glad I know Johannes' algorithms and I hope they will be better for some circumstances that will occur later, but I stop coding functions for loading the distances for now.

Answer (score 3):

Break it into another table called "distance" that relates back to the original "place" table:

create table distance (place_id_1 int, place_id_2 int, distance int);

That is, for each place, calculate the distance for another place and save it in this new table.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new table with two columns as foreign keys for the locations and one column for the distance between them.

```
 |place1 | place2 | distance
-+-------|--------|---------
 |....   |.....   | .....
```

Depends on how many locations you have, this table could grow very fast.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is make another table which will contain two places id and the distance like

```
place1    place2    distance
a         b          20
c         d          30
```

in the time of fetching data just join it with place table.

Answer (score -1):

I think something like this could do the job.

```
         ORIGIN     | CITY 1 | CITY 2 | CITY 3 | CITY 4 | CITY 5
         +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
         CITY 1        0        20                 40      20
         CITY 5        10       50       20                0
         CITY 3        10                0         10      40
```

You can easily get the distances to other places and the you don't need to store the names of the cities for each distance you know.

```
SELECT 'CITY 2' FROM DISTANCES WHERE ORIGIN='CITY 5'
```

Comment: -1. Using a pivot table is more efficient and easier to maintain. For example with this setup you cannot ensure unique indexing, which you can do with pivot tables.

Comment: Would you add new columns to that table, then update all existing rows to add a new value for its distance as new cities are registered? That would be awful.

Comment: A pivot table basically is just used to store data for entries in another table. therefore it does not need its own primary key, but uses the keys of the other table. See my answer for an example of how to use a pivot table here.